# Вход в админ панель по спец ключу

Tags: php, безопасность

Когда-то делал такую авторизацию в админке. Суть заключается в следующем:

- Создаем файл типа `file.key`.
- Генерируем спец ключ с помощью `crypt('string')` и сохраняем в файл.
- Этот же ключ записываем в БД.

Вход в админ панель происходит следующим образом:

- Жмем **Обзор** находим на компе файлик, и жмем отправить.
- Считываем файлик и сверяем с тем, что записан в БД. Все совпадает, милости просим. + (считываем расширение файла, т.к. его можно придумать вообще каким угодно)

Удобно если:

- Система не будет передаваться или продаваться.
- Системой пользуется ограниченное количество людей (допустим, в офисе).

Вот интересует ваше мнение с точки зрения безопасности и т.п. Конечно, речь идет не о банальных блогах, а о серьезных проектах.

Comment: SSL и не паримся.

Comment: Подскажите поподробнее как создать файл  file.key
Возникла проблема входа в админку, а ключа нету. Могу написать логин и пароль которые прописаны в БД

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Я понимаю когда люди пытаются усилить защиту используя зашифрованный протокол. Но в этом случае, я наблюдаю всего лишь дополнительную мороку для конечного пользователя. Учтите также тот факт, что защита в таких случаях строится на утверждении что злоумышленник имеет доступ к прослушиванию линии. В этих условиях ваша защита не более чем глупый маневр.

Comment: Дождался достойный ответ. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Файлик можно пербросить,  и вся затея рухнет... Не лутше тогда смотреть айпишник?
А если интересно входы с разных компов под одной учеткой то можно связывать вход с Вконтактом или фейсБуком благо можно и удобно и поинтересней будет.

Comment: Тогда взлом акка ВК = взлом админки. Ничего интересного.

Answer (score 3):

Все тот же самый shared secret, вид сбоку. Если допустима нестандартность подхода и хочется нормального решения — используйте HTTPS и клиентские сертификаты.

Видимые плюсы:

- Некоторая нестандартность решения. Защищает от кейлоггеров и типичных снифферов, ловящих POST-запросы.
- Эффективный размер ключа выше, чем у типичного пароля. Повышает качество, защищая от слабых паролей. Хотя защищаться от брутфорса в любом случае нужно не так.

Видимые минусы:

- Ключ выдается, а не задается, что несколько повышает возможность его утечки (т.к. знают пользователь и администратор, а не один пользователь).
- Если браузеры хранят пароли хоть как-то их защищая (например, мастер-паролем), то файл хранится без всякой защиты или даже обфускации. Тащи с диска и пользуйся.
- Функция `crypt(3)` в типичных вариантах (использующая DES, MD5 или варианты SHA) не рекомендуется для хранения хэшей. [Рекомендуют](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/web_security/117005/) [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Answer (score 2):

Интересная идея, делающая невозможным брутфорс со стороны фронт-энда админки. При условии, конечно, что в файле бинарные данные, а не текст.

Comment: И я о чем. Естественно что бинарные данные. Но вот великие брутфорсеры говорят другое!

Answer (score 1):

Такой способ гораздо безопасней, чем тот же логин / пароль. За условием, что всё сделано верно.

Answer (score 1):

Например, можно сделать, чтобы админ входил только через обычного пользователя. Т.е. сначала залогинился обычным пользователем, потом - админка. И никак иначе.
И это все логируется. Будет видно по крайней мере, кто брутфорсит :) И защита тогда проще строится.
Но еще и SSL конечно.

Answer (score -1):

И одним ключём все входят.
если я правильно понял вашу затею

Comment: Ну я думаю что лучше не одним. Допустим сотрудник уволился, сносим ключ в БД который ему выдавался и Good Bye)